# Prove convergence of alternating sum with positive and negative terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

I am trying to find under which conditions does the sum below converge to 0,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)}^{n+1}\cos(b\log(n))({n}^{a-1}-{n}^{-a})=0,$

with b and a real numbers, with 0 < a < 1.

I know that this sum is conditionally convergent as its absolute value diverges. Furthermore I cannot use the alternating series test as the terms of the sum are not all positive and not all negative.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the context of this question? That will help us know what tools are available to you. (Special case, by the way—when $a=\frac12$ the series is absolutely convergent, for trivial reasons.)

Comment: Hi @GregMartin ! Thank you for your fast response. 

I need to know when is this sum equal to 0. As you have stated the trivial case is a = 1/2. My method was to show that this series is convergent only at a = 1/2, and no other value of a, then and only then the sum is equal to 0. 

There are 3 case when the sum is 0, a=1/2 (a trivial solution), the cos is 0 (not possible as b is a constant so not all terms will vanish), or groups of terms cancel out. The last one is the hard one.

Comment: Is it a homework problem from a course? Is it part of a research project? Something in between?

Comment: It is not homework. It’s a part of a research project that I am investigating for my own leisure.

Comment: @OolongMilktea thank you for answer. The speed of growth log(n) changes the frequency at which the cosine oscillates, which makes it particularly tricky.

Comment: It's not as tricky as you thought. $|\cos(b\log(n+1))-\cos(b\log n)|<\frac{b}{n}$ is enough to conclude the sum converge in Riemann's sense.

Comment: @OolongMilktea it is true that with the inequality you gave it seems to be more doable. I don’t see however where you got it from? And if you find it trivial, could you add two or three more steps to your conclusion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather write this as an answer.
Now we have an alternating series and add together every 2 term, that is
$$\cos(b\log (2n-1))((2n-1)^{a-1}-(2n-1)^{-a})-\cos(b\log 2n)(2n^{a-1}-2n^{-a})\\
=\cos(b\log (2n-1))[((2n-1)^{a-1}-2n^{a-1})-((2n-1)^{-a}-2n^{-a})]\\
-[\cos(b\log 2n)-\cos(b\log (2n-1))](2n^{a-1}-2n^{-a})$$

For the first term $\cos(b\log (2n-1))$ is bounded by $1$, $((2n-1)^{a-1}-2n^{a-1})$ grows at the same rate as $a(2n)^{a-2}$ and similarly $((2n-1)^{-a}-2n^{-a})$ at $a(2n)^{-a-1}$, so the first part absolutely converge.

For the second part, use the inequality
$$|\cos(b\log(2n))-\cos(b\log (2n-1)|=|\int_{2n-1}^{2n} -\sin(\cos(b\log x))\frac{b}{x} dx|<\int_{2n-1}^{2n}|\frac{b}{2n}| dx<\frac{b}{2n}$$
So the second term grows at the rate of $O(n^{a-2})+O(n^{-a-1})$, also absolutely convergent.

I don't know if the original series absolutely converges, which needs far more effort to verify.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It is very clear now. Nonetheless as you said the original series requires more work. It’s a good starting point.

Comment: This is definitely the right idea (group consecutive terms together), although the details could be simplified by just applying the mean value theorem to the function $\cos(b \log x)(x^{a-1}-x^{-a})$.